# Graph coloring and eigenvalues

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I hit a stone wall with this particular problem as graph coloring was not a topic covered in any of my courses. I would appreciate any help:
Let G = (V, E) be a d-regular n-vertex graph that is 3-colourable and such that
there is a 3-colouring in which the colour classes have equal size |V |/3. Let A be the adjacency matrix and L be the Laplacian of G given by  L = I − 1/d A .

Let $$λ_1 ≤ λ_2 ≤ · · · ≤ λ_n$$ be the eigenvalues of the Laplacian.

1)Prove that L has at least two eigenvalues which are greater than or equal to 3/2,that is, λn−1 ≥ 3/2

2) Then there should be given an example in which the bound the tight.

3) Finally we must show that the converse is not true.

Comment: The "graph coloring" is only one way to explain that you have a tri-partite graph, with each set having the same size $|V|/3$. 
You don't need any specific result from graph coloring.

Comment: Note that the definition you gave of the Laplacian of $G$ is not the "standard Laplacian", rather the normalized laplacian. Using standard notation, you want to proove that for any tripartite $d$-regular graph with $n_1=n_2=n_3$, you have
$$ \mu_{n-1} \geq \frac{3d}{2}$$
The graph $K_3$ is 2-regular, tripartite with each class of size 1, and it attains this bound ($spec(L(K_3))=\{3,3,0\}$)

I'm looking at a way to proove the first statement. In the third, what is meant by "the converse" Should we exhibit a graph with $\mu_{n-1} \geq 3d/2$ wich is not tripartite etc. should be easy